# Adding credential(username and password) and fetching URL in python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I add credential(username and password) and then fetch the URL of that particular website in python?
I need help to implement this in my project

Example: suppose the first page is the login page and when we provide the credential and validate that and then we are re-directed into the homepage and then pick the url of that homepage

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem statement. It will be really helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: So you want the url of the `homepage` like `http://dns/homepage` ?

Comment: yes @kedarnag using python

Comment: can you try `self.request.url` ?

Comment: ok will try, but how can I login with credential

Comment: Are you trying to build Authentication feature ? Like login using email & password ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use package `os`

```
import os
url = os.environ['HTTP_HOST']
uri = os.environ['REQUEST_URI']
return url+uri
```